# Implicit use of this keyword

Tags: java

When does Java compiler automatically append this keyword in my class?

```
public class Alphabets
{
    int a;

    public void gen_1(int b)
    {
        a=b;   //equivalent to this.a=b
        gen_2();   //is this equivalent to Alphabets.gen_2()  or this.gen_2?
    }

    public static void gen_2()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Why, because developers are lazy!  Seriously, when I started with Java, the only IDEs that were available was NotePad (or basically any other text editor), no auto completion or auto correct, so, having to type `this` a thousand times would drive you nuts fast. As to *"is this Alphabets.gen_2() or this.gen_2?"* it's `this.gen_2()`

Comment: @MadProgrammer `gen_2` in this example is static.

Comment: @ernest_k Ok, my bad then it's `Alphabets.gen_2()`

Comment: I don't think the compiler "automatically appends" `this`. All that it needs to know is the target object to run non-static methods on and the class to run static methods on... And the only difference between the two is just that instance methods are executed in the context of an object. Otherwise the method linking is the same. The rest is just about how it goes about linking methods when the developer didn't explicitly qualify them, and that's just about it.

Comment: Because it's static, it's an `invokestatic #? // Method Alphabets.gen_2:()V`, not `aload 0; invokevirtual #? // Method Alphabets.gen_2:()V`.

Comment: @ernest_k In a sense, the compiler does prepend `this` - that is, it has to push the receiver of the call (`this`) on the stack, even if you don't mention `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever it wouldn't compile without it. It's not so much that `javac` 'adds the `this.` for you' - it's that `javac` will interpret a certain expression in a certain way.

In your example, `a` is equivalent to `this.a` not because "java will add the `this.`" - it's equivalent because just `a` and `this.a` refer to the same thing: The only `a` that is in scope. Java will look at the closest matching name in scope. Example:

```
int a = 2;
void example() {
  int a = 5;
  {
     int b = 10;
     {
        System.out.println(a);
     }
  }
}
```

2 scopes up, there's an `a` (a local var, being assigned the value of 5). It's closer than the field. Not in literal 'how many lines in the source file is it removed from this line', but in the: "Start looking in the nearest set of {}, if you can't find it there, look in the next set, and just keep going until you find it" way.

For that reason, `gen_2()` does not 'generate `this.`', because that's not how you should think about it. It looks for a method named `gen_2` (why a method? Because there are parentheses hanging off of the end of it), and finds one in the `Alphabets {}` scope. That's the one it'll invoke. It'll do this in a static fashion, because the method is static. Not because java 'generates `Alphabets.`'.

Answer (score 1):

Any programming language has to have rules about how the compiler determines the meaning of a name.  Java is no exception; its rules are [in Chapter 6 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.2).

The full set of rules is quite elaborate, but the simplified answer to your question is: if there's an unqualified name that identifies something that is a member of the current object, and it is not obscured by a more local declaration of the same name, then the name means the member of the current object, i.e., 'this' is implied.